# Can we create a migration for the data, not just structure of the tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I love laravel because of the ability to create migrations.

From what I understood, laravel gives us the capability to create a migration where we can repeat the same process without having to create tables and structures manually.
My Question:

Similarly,

1) If I want that my data (inputs to the table) is also stored in some way, so that whenever i change the data in the database, that can also be reverted back or the whole process can also be recreated.

2) If 1 is not possible then can we have a way to save the methods for the "initial" seeding of the database. (so when we "factory" reset the whole thing, it can also automatically populate the content of the database, not just the structure of the database)

*Any references for the same please?*

I hope I was able to make myself clear!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct in assuming Laravel is incredible! So with respect to your first question.

> 1) If I want that my data (inputs to the table) are also stored in some way, so that whenever i change the data in the database, that can also be reverted back or the whole process can also be recreated.

If you you want to recreate the data you will need to create a table seeder. To do this, simply create a seeder and a factory with artisan.

> php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder

After making your seeder you can run it this with command:

> composer dump-autoload && php artisan db:seed

If you wanted to create Controllers, Seeders and Factories at the same time when you make a model type this artisan command.

> php artisan make:model User -fa

You can see more on the Laravel documentation for creating seeders and factories [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding).

Instead of messing with your migration files, I would create seeders. Here is a couple examples.

**Exhibit 1 - Example of a an Article Factory (database/factories/ArticleFactory.php)**

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Article::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->text(50),
        'slug' => $faker->unique()->slug,
        'body' => $faker->text(200),
        'user_id' => rand(1,10),
    ];
});
```

**Exhibit 2 - Example of an Article Seeder (database/seeds/ArticleTableSeeder.php)**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ArticlesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Article::class, 10)->create();
    }
}
```

**Exhibit 3 - Example of an Article Migration (database/migrations/2018_05_13_create_articles_table.php)**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateArticlesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->integer('media_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('user_id')->nullable(); // Owner of Article
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->index('slug');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('articles');
    }
}
```

**Exhibit 4 - DatabaseTableSeeder.php**

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // Disable all mass assignment restrictions
        Model::unguard();


        // Seeds the Articles
        $this->call(ArticlesTableSeeder::class);
```

Then to do a complete factory reset, all you need to do is type the following artisan command:

> php artisan migrate:db --fresh
>
> php artisan db:seed

Comment: I got confused because I saw so many tuts online talking about "fakers". So my mind automatically went on to believe that we could only fake data not insert real data. 
Thanks. This helped much :)

Comment: Seeders are mostly useful to generate test data ase they are meant to be re-used (thus fakers). I personally consider it perfectly fine to use migration to seed data in production, because this is surely something you want to be able to rollback and run only once (which the migration can do by design).

Comment: If I run the seed command will it run all seeders every time, or does it already know what has already been run in the past?

Answer (score 4):

Answer 1) Yes you can manually automatically insert your data into your tables each time you run your migrations.

Answer 2) Question one is possible

Example:

```
public function up()
{
    // Create the table
    Schema::create('users', function($table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email', 255);
        $table->string('password', 64);
        $table->boolean('verified');
        $table->string('token', 255);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    // Insert some stuff
    DB::table('users')->insert(
        array(
            'email' => 'name@domain.com',
            'verified' => true
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: wow. this is much simpler than i had thought and obviously so so obvious :D

Comment: @NishantSah Yep it can be slightly confusing at first while you get used to the migrations syntax, but worth it. Be sure to check out the laraval docs as they are really useful! Good luck

Comment: @d3r0x have been trying to read them, see videos but I still am no where close to having a grip on the advanced features. 
More over am using a framework for the first time, so that took me a few days to understand. 
Its a huge jump for someone who did php 10 yrs back :D like alice in wonderland ;)

Answer (score 2):

Although you can do data migrations by both using a migration file or a seeder file (as explained in the above answers), from experience I strongly recommend that you put such migration code inside a seeder file, not a migration file.

The reason being is that it's very difficult to run a single file migration. Migrations are designed to run all at once, or to run migrations in step by step sequence since the last migration was done, migrations are not designed to be cherry picked individually, see migration help:

```
 php artisan migrate --help
Usage:
  migrate [options]

Options:
      --database[=DATABASE]  The database connection to use.
      --force                Force the operation to run when in production.
      --path[=PATH]          The path of migrations files to be executed.
      --pretend              Dump the SQL queries that would be run.
      --seed                 Indicates if the seed task should be re-run.
      --step                 Force the migrations to be run so they can be rolled back individually.
  -h, --help                 Display this help message
  -q, --quiet                Do not output any message
  -V, --version              Display this application version
      --ansi                 Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi              Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction       Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]            The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose       Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Help:
  Run the database migrations
```

you will notice that there is no option available to run a handpicked migration, something that you may want to do some day with your data migration (example: suppose you simply want to take data from one legacy table to another table, think of it as moving data from a transactional database to an analytics database using a nightly cron job or something).

This option is however available in a seeder:

```
php artisan db:seed --help
Usage:
  db:seed [options]

Options:
      --class[=CLASS]        The class name of the root seeder [default:
```

which makes it much more flexible than a migration (not to mention that seeding data is all about data, which is more appropriate for your task)